# Riddle: Where does a Non Jew have more Halachic power than a Jew?

Tags: talmud-gemara, riddle

When a Non Jew does something it would work according to Halacha, however when a Jew does the same thing it is useless.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Negating an *avoda zara*.  If a non-Jew takes an idol and says "I reject this!" and damages it, the idol is no longer prohibited from benefit.  A Jew can't do that.

Answer (score 19):

If an animal was mostly slaughtered by a Jew (the majority but not all of the trachea & esophagus were cut) and the animal is not dying, a non-Jew can kill it however he wants and the animal will be kosher.  If a Jew shechted the rest of the way, it would be a shihiyah b'miut batra (a pause in the final portion) and the animal is neveila (not kosher).  But since the slaughter of a non-Jew is nothing, the majority slaughtered by the Jew is all that counts.

(See Shulchan Aruch YD 23:5)

Comment: Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for that fascinating bit of Halacha!

Answer (score 7):

If a non-Jew does *m'lacha* for himself on *Shabas*, a Jew can use the result immediately; not so if a Jew does. (As always, CYLOR.)

Answer (score 3):

A non-jew can taste a mixture of food to tell if the prohibited substance (e.g. milk in meat) inside gave taste.

Comment: If a Jew did so for some reason (e.g. he had a blood-sugar emergency), we would trust him, just as an Ashkenazi can trust a Sefardi who trusts a non-Jew, or we can taste a fleishig-sliced onion for meatiness.

Comment: Avoda Zara the non jew changes the status - by tasting food the jew still is the one who determines whether the food is Kosher.

Answer (score 1):

A non-Jew can run a kosher establishment without the certifiers worrying (as much) about him owning chametz over pesach, toveling all the kelim, etc..